# requirejs multiple requires in a row

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs, require, requirejs-define

I wrote a JavaScript module loader which defines different modules within a loop..

```
function(moduleList) {
    var arr = [];
    for (i = 0, l = moduleList.length; i < l; i++) {
        var m = moduleList[i];

        define(m.guid, function() {
            return  {
                container : m.container,
                configuration : m.configuration,
                moduleId : m.id
            }
        });
        arr[i] = m;
    }
}
```

Directly after that there is the next for loop in which I "require" the previously defined modules..

```
for (i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {   
   require([arr[i].id,arr[i].guid], function(module, moduleConfiguration) {
        core.utils.log("m.id: " + moduleConfiguration.moduleId);
        core.utils.log("init " + moduleConfiguration.moduleId, moduleConfiguration);

        module.init(moduleConfiguration);
    });
}
```

The problem now is that inside every "require" block the moduleConfiguration and module is the same.. To make a "require" call it uses different ids but the result is always the same.

Does somebody know how to find a way arround this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your definition function should look like this, so that "m" is properly scoped:

```
function(moduleList) {
    var arr = [], i; // declare i!!!!
    function def(m) {
        define(m.guid, function() {
            return  {
                container : m.container,
                configuration : m.configuration,
                moduleId : m.id
            }
        });
    }

    for (i = 0, l = moduleList.length; i < l; i++) {

        var m = moduleList[i];

        def(m);
        arr[i] = m;
    }
 }
```

In your code, the same variable "m" is shared among all those module callbacks. By introducing another function (and another scope), you make sure that each callback has its own copy.